# Login to HTTPS website programmatically using C# with form values in Hebrew

Tags: c#, html, forms

I'm trying to login to a website that has authentication form

```
<form name="logon" action="login.php" method="POST" >
  <input type="text" name="id_num" value="">
  <input type="password" name="password" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="התחברות" name="connect">
</form>
```

I also snipped the data with Data Tamper.
Data Tamper shows the the keys and values and for `connect` is shows `%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA` that is the url encoding for that word.
I'm unable to login with C# code apprerantly because of the submit button with the Hebrew value.
any help?

Answer (score 0):

Create a View Model for this form with a property for the submit.  Then, upon processing, check to see if the value for the submit property is null.

Comment: I'm passing the data as string, how can I isolate it from the other members?

Comment: I just realized there's something about this question I'm not getting.  You're using a PHP script for processing the form submission.  What part is actually C# related?

Comment: The whole code is in C#, sorry if I confused with PHP

Comment: But your processing script is done by a PHP script.  If your intention is to use C# to process your form then why have you chosen the form action to be "login.php?"

Comment: I'm trying to login to an existing website not create one of my own... The code block is copied from the actual website.